# How to save user interactions with the webpage so next time user signs in and sees where he left

Tags: php, backend

I have a webpage with a chart where a user interacts with the chart and changes some elements. This is only client side by now.

How can I keep this state so the next time when the user signs he sees where he left and which changes he made.

This is a small personal project so not many users but just want to understand how this is done.

Comment: In every page, execute an XmlHttpRequest (AJAX) that sends a query to a PHP page that stores the current window.location in a session field. When user signs in next time, if session field is valid, redirect user to that page.

Comment: @PEMapModder: Thank you for your answer what is this process called can you point me to a good tutorial for that?

Comment: Search for Ajax and PHP sessions. We don't recommend tutorials on StackOverflow.